# How to slower the internet connection on MacOs for development purposes

Tags: ios, macos, osx-snow-leopard

What tool can I use to slower the internet connection on MacOs for development purposes?

Comment: [Check this](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/12/throttling-bandwidth-on-a-mac.html) and [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080119112509736)

Answer (score 2):

[Network Link Conditioner.](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/)